# Why/how can i use bash commands such as 'apt-get' and 'sudo' (Nearly Free Speech)?

Tags: apache, nearlyfreespeech

I am using NearlyFreeSpeech Server Type Apache 2.4 Generic, logged in via ssh and wondering why I'm getting this message:

[image]

Comment: Check your PATH variable (`echo $PATH`), it must be very limited not to have these command's paths.  hum, or they do not let your do that, you must check with them.

Comment: @Nic3500 thank you for your reply, **/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin** is what i get when i execture echo $PATH

Comment: These commands are usually in /usr/bin.  So it's not that.  Then you can do `sudo -l` to see what you are allowed to do. I suspect NearlyFreeSpeech do not allow you to install anything.  They host sites, not linux VM.  Contact them, that is as much as we can do.